# Mathematical Operations with Typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I'm trying to divide a number (12 in my case, due to using Foundation's Front End framework) by the number of pages that will appear in the typoscript-rendered menu of a page and output the result as part of a class name of the html menu items.

Currently, I can get typoscript to output the number of items in a menu with `{register:count_menuItems}`, but I can't figure out how to divide this number and output the quotient.

Below is my code:

```
lib.navigation.secondary = HMENU
lib.navigation.secondary {
    entryLevel = 1

    stdWrap.dataWrap = <div class="row large-10 small-centered large-centered columns">|</div>
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        NO {
            allWrap = <div class="large-{register:count_menuItems} small-12 columns first">|</div> |*| <div class="large-{register:count_menuItems} small-12 columns">|</div> |*| <div class="large-{register:count_menuItems} small-12 columns last">|</div>
            allWrap.insertData = 1

            stdWrap.cObject = COA
            stdWrap.cObject {

             # getting the navigation title with fallback to the title
                10 = TEXT
                10.field = nav_title // title
                10.wrap = <h4>|</h4>

            # getting the subtitle of the page
                20 = TEXT
                20.field = subtitle
                20.wrap = <p>|</p>

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following ended up working for me

```
NO {
    before.cObject = LOAD_REGISTER
    before.cObject {
        menuItems.cObject = TEXT
        menuItems.cObject {
            current = 1
            setCurrent.data = register:count_menuItems
            setCurrent.wrap = 12/|
            prioriCalc = 1     
        }
    }

    allWrap = <div class="large-{register:count_menuItems} small-12 columns first">|</div> |*| <div class="large-{register:count_menuItems} small-12 columns">|</div> |*| <div class="large-{register:count_menuItems} small-12 columns last">|</div>
    allWrap.insertData = 1

    ...
```

Comment: Despite this working for me, I'd love to see a more concise implementation!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't test it, but I think you can solve it by this approach:

First create a LOAD_REGISTER containing the result of the calculation:

```
page.5 = LOAD_REGISTER
# the default value
page.5.divClass = 12
page.5.divClass.cObject = TEXT
page.5.divClass.cObject {
  value = 12
  stdWrap.dataWrap = |/{register:count_menuItems}
  prioriCalc = 1
}
```

Then use it in your navigation:

```
lib.navigation.secondary = HMENU
lib.navigation.secondary {
    entryLevel = 1

    stdWrap.dataWrap = <div class="row large-10 small-centered large-centered columns">|</div>
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        NO {
            allWrap = <div class="large-{register:divClass} small-12 columns first">|</div> |*| <div class="large-{register:divClass} small-12 columns">|</div> |*| <div class="large-{register:divClass} small-12 columns last">|</div>
            allWrap.insertData = 1

[...]
```

The tricky part could be the rendering order of the menu; I'm not sure if at the time you're creating your LOAD_REGISTER divClass the register count_menuItems is already available.

Comment: This was on the right track because of the need to use LOAD_REGISTER, but it looks as though it had to be created as a cObject